# Adding "please wait loading...." before video starts playing

Tags: android, android-videoview

My app has a button which when clicked plays a video in dailog box. I want to add "please wait loading..." text in the dailog box while the video loads before playing. I tried of adding a progress bar but the progress bar is not visible before the video plays

Here is the code I tried

```
public void plyvido(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.videodialog);
    dialog.show();
    MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
        MainActivity.this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());

    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

    videoview = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.videodialogVideoView);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
    videoview.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoview.start();



    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.start();
                mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1,
                                                       int arg2) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });

            }
        });


}
```

Comment: try to play video after on onPrepared()

Comment: @Androider Still no change

Answer (score 1):

Make the root layout of videodailog.XML a relative layout and add

**In videoview tag**

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

**In progress bar tab**

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this:**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);  
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

**To Hide it:**

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false)
```

Comment: Tried as you said bro. But its the same again. Can't see the progress bar

Comment: try checking your xml if its invisible...and try extending the activity with ActionBar and try running...

Comment: Tried if . still no change. The code is working fine if I don't have the dailog box

Comment: Yah will do . This problem became a pain for me. Can't we at least display "please wait loading..." instead of the progress bar

Comment: you can add a screen specifying please wait ...and when the video starts loading...remove the screen and display the video screen